# How to find which script modifies css of selected attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, dom

Is there a way to get information which scripts modified selected DOM element, and in which order?

On my website, I modify width of div A. It appears however, that some other script modifies that width after that, but I do not know which script it is. How can I find it?

Edit:
After searching a bit more, I fount that in firebug you can right click attribute in HTML view, and select "stop javascript on change" (or sth similar, my firefox is not in english), the problem being it resets after reloading the page, what makes it useles for me.

Comment: Where is link on site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using chrome developer tools to debug my page. It supports add breakpoints to dom elements, when attributes of dom is modified by javascript, it breaks the rendering process immediately. I think you can try it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried that, the thing is those break points appear to reset when I refresh the page, and the change I'm looking for happens too fast for me to catch it.

Comment: @Xyzk - in that case you can try to write "breakpoint" yourself, using Mutation events (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)